# Help with an assignment please

Tags: security

I have 2 questions I'm having trouble finding info for.
Q1 what are names of 2 main editions for ubuntu?
Q2 name 4 security features for ubuntu.

Comment: Let me google that for you http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+editions

Comment: This site isn't a place to ask other people to provide answers for your school work.

Comment: I've added the links below.
For future reference, please consult resources such as Google.

Answer (score 1):

### Editions:

See Ubuntu [editions](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours).

### Security Features:

See Ubuntu security [features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features).

Answer (score 0):

Q1

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
- Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)

Q2

- No Open Ports
- Password hashing
- SYN cookies
- Configurable Firewall